# how to count a change in the categorical column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have a below dataframe:

```
OUTLET_UNQ_CODE  Category_Code   month

0   2018020000065   SSSI    January 21

1   2018020000066   SSSI    January 21

2   2018020000067   SSSI    January 21

...

512762  2021031641195   CH  March 21

512763  2021031642445   CH  March 21

512764  2021031643357   GM  March 21

512765  2021031643863   GM  March 21
```

there are few OUTLET_UNQ_CODE who have changed their Category_Code within a month and next month as well. I need to count the number of hops every outlet has done. For ex: If 2021031643863 had Category_code GM in Jan 21 and CH in Jan 21 again, CH in Feb and Kirana in March. This will be counted as 2 hops.

This is what i have tried:

```
s=pd.to_numeric(new_df.Category_Code,errors='coerce') 

df=new_df.assign(New=s.bfill())[s.isnull()].groupby('OUTLET_UNQ_CODE').agg({'Category_Code':list}) 

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

O/P is:

```
   OUTLET_UNQ_CODE  Category_Code

0   2021031643863   [GM,CH,CH,Kirana]
```

Comment: what have you tried? show us some code.

Comment: s=pd.to_numeric(new_df.Category_Code,errors='coerce') df=new_df.assign(New=s.bfill())[s.isnull()].groupby('OUTLET_UNQ_CODE').agg({'Category_Code':list}) df df.reset_index(inplace=True) df.head() #this code has grouped the category codes on the basis of outlet code and has given list as a category code. OUTLET_UNQ_CODE Category_Code 0 2021031643863 [GM, CH, CH, Kirana]

Comment: please add that code to your question and format it as code so it is easier to read.

Comment: If I understand it right how the hops are counted, you just need to change the `list` to a `set` (uniqe members of the list) and get length of the `set` minus 1.

Comment: yes, that will work for most of the cases but [GM,CH,GM,CH,GM] these are 4 hops and if i use set it will be only considered as 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regardless if there is maybe a better way starting from the beginning, to achieve the goal based on your output, here is a piece of code to get the number of changes in the list:

```
cat_lst = ['GM','CH','CH','Kirana']
a = sum((1 for i,x in enumerate(cat_lst[:-1]) if x!= cat_lst[i+1]))

# in this case the result of a is 2
```

Comment: This actually worked. Thanks a lot :)